# Allow requests to redirect with Python to read webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, redirect, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to load websites and read their visible text with python, but some sites in my list fail to load properly because they don't successfully redirect to the main website page. e.g. the url imfuna.com should redirect to imfuna.com/home-uk/ but it doesn't, and therefore my code only retrieves 6 words rather than the 64 it should.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# error handling

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

# settings

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

url = "http://imfuna.com"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

front_text_count = len(text.split(" "))
print front_text_count
print text
```

If you run this you only get 6 words:

```
6
Imfuna Property Inventory and Inspection Apps
```

But really you should get 64 (a browser redirects to http://imfuna.com/home-uk/ and would see the content there).

Anyone know how I can set requests to allow the redirect to occur and to instead parse the page at http://imfuna.com/home-uk/

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm running it in python 3 and getting `63` words.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar that's interesting but I can't think of any reason at all that it should be different in 3 - can you suggest any changes to make?

Comment: try this - `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=True )`

Comment: Actually `http://imfuna.com` redirects to `http://www.imfuna.com` not to `http://imfuna.com/home-uk/`

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar Mhmm, I still only get 6 words :/ Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't think of anything else. :/ why don't you directly visit the page ? :/

Comment: ...because it's part of a bigger script that reads quotes from websites according to certain parameters... and therefore, getting the program to be able to parse the webpage text is pretty important!